# Animate CC Flash CC: Using variable with HTML5 canvas call

Tags: javascript, html, flash, canvas, animate-cc

So I'm trying to create a function that I can reuse with a variable, but I can't figure out how to implement it with the .bind()-function. I want to replace `target` with `movie_clip_1` (or `movie_clip_2` etc.)
Here's my Animate CC Action-code:

```
this.nav_core_btn.addEventListener("click", fl_playClip.bind(this, movie_clip_1));

function fl_playClip(target) {
    this.target.gotoAndPlay(1);

}
```

Error message says:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: clip_core_inner is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your function is calling the parameter passed down to the function body. See that I'm not using the `this`, but instead `target`, that is passed as a function argument.

I've also mocked the object, so that you understand:

```
var btnPlay = document.querySelector('#btnPlay')
var movie_clip_1 = {
  gotoAndPlay: function () {
    console.log('Mock!')
  }
}
btnPlay.addEventListener("click", fl_playClip.bind(this, movie_clip_1));

function fl_playClip(target) {
  target.gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

You can see a live example here: http://jsbin.com/vozififoze/1/edit?html,js,console,output

If you read the example I've provided, you can start answering your own questions:

- How to create a function that I can reuse?
  Pass a variable, and reference that inside the function body.
- How use the bind() function?
  Check the docs at ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind ), where it says that you should pass a context and the arguments.

To see what you're doing wrong, let's see how to call the function `this.target.gotoAndPlay` properly, where you'll notice that it ignores the parameter/argument that is passed down to the function:

```
function fl_playClip(target) {
  this.target.gotoAndPlay(1);
}

fl_playClip.prototype = {
  target: {
    gotoAndPlay: function () {
      console.log('my gotoAndPlay output!')
    }
  }
}

new fl_playClip(null)
```

The output here is `my gotoAndPlay output!`